# ngrx effect creates an infinite loop

Tags: angular, ngrx

I'm new in ngrx and new in this project team.when I click on user's name to give their realted charts my app hangs and I think that's beacuase ngrx effect creates an infinite loop. here is the effect code:

```
      @Effect()
myObjectivesRequested$ = this.actions$
    .pipe(
        ofType<MyObjectivesRequested>(ObjectivesActionTypes.MyObjectivesRequested),
        mergeMap(({payload}) => {
            this.store.dispatch(this.showActionLoadingDistpatcher);
            return this.store.pipe(select(selectMyObjectivesIdsByCompanyId(payload.companyId))).pipe(
                take(1),
                mergeMap(myObjectives => {
                    if (myObjectives) {
                        return of(myObjectives);
                    } else {
                        return this.ObjectivesService.getMyObjectives(payload.companyId).pipe(
                            take(1),
                            map(res => {
                                return this.store.dispatch(new MyObjectivesLoaded({objectives: res, companyId: payload.companyId}));
                            })
                        );
                    }
                }));
        }),
        map(() => {
            return this.hideActionLoadingDistpatcher;
        }),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, it is weird that you are using `take(1)`. `take(1)` takes the first emission and closes the observable stream (making it dead). I see you are seeing if what you are looking for exists in the store or not before making an API call, making your store a cache.

I would do:

```
@Effect()
myObjectivesRequested$ = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType<MyObjectivesRequested>(ObjectiveActionTypes.MyObjectivesRequested),
  switchMap(({ payload }) => {
    return this.store.pipe(
             select(selectMyObjectivesIdsByCompanyId(payload.companyId)),
             switchMap(myObjectives => {
               if (myObjectives) {
                 return of(myObjectives);
               } else {
                 return this.ObjectivesService.getMyObjectives(payload.companyId);
               }
            }),
            map(objectives => new MyObjectivesLoaded({objectives, companyId: payload.companyId}))
           ),
            // catch the error, return the action (this is optional)
            catchError(error => Observable.of(new MyObjectivesError(error))
  })
)
```

Some notes:

1.) `select(selectMyObjectivesIdsByCompanyId(payload.companyId))` should be a variable in
a selectors file.

2.) I see your dispatching actions using the store in your effect. In your reducer, listen to `MyObjectivesRequested` and turn the `loading` to on. Listen to `MyObjectivesLoaded` and populate the data/objectives slice and turn `loading` to off. Listen to `MyObjectivesError` and turn the `loading` to off and `error` to whatever the error is.
You should then have selectors like you do for `selectMyObjectivesIdsByCompanyId` (this is data/objectives slice) for `loading` and `error` as well and use these selectors in your component to see what's going on in the state.

A good repository related to `ngrx` => https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-NgRx-GettingStarted where Demo5 is the most advanced (all of the concepts built in).